# nodemon crashes after adding its' dependencies

Tags: mean, nodemon

I can't seem to track down why nodemon is crashing after it loads its dependencies and starts.  I'm doing a MEAN API tutorial and I want to use it to automate restarting the node server.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the stacktrace:

```
C:\nodeprojects\bookstore>npm install -g nodemon
C:\Users\brohj_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon -> C:\Users\brohj_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js

> nodemon@1.14.11 postinstall C:\Users\brohj_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon
> node -e "console.log('\u001b[32mLove nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[96m\u001b[1mhttps://opencollective.com/nodemon/donat
e\u001b[0m\n')" || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ nodemon@1.14.11
added 247 packages in 103.866s

C:\nodeprojects\bookstore>nodemon
[nodemon] 1.14.11
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Running on port 3000...
(node:6748) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1257:14)
    at listen (net.js:1293:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1389:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (C:\nodeprojects\bookstore\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodeprojects\bookstore\app.js:15:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Did you `Ctrl+C` when nodemon was running ?

Comment: No, the node server is still running in a separate CLI on port 3000.

Comment: Try to close node server by end process (in Processes tab) in Task manager and run the server again. If it's still crashed then there must be something wrong in your code.

Comment: I stopped the node server and restarted and nodeman still crashed.

Comment: The code is exactly as the tutorial.  I can't post it here because it exceeds the character limit.  So let's assume the code is correct...can we extrapolate what's wrong by looking at the stacktrace?

Comment: You're right...problem in my code.  I didn't have the correct ' ' marks around a folder directory in app.js.  Thanks for making me look harder. :-)

Comment: glad to here it :) good luck further